# Why is Axios not recognizing correct information?

Tags: javascript, axios, json-server

I am working on a practice login page in JS and JSON server as well as Axios. I am trying to verify that the username and password being entered are indeed on the DB. However it seems that even if I enter a username that I have already stored in the DB it will return as if it is false. Here is how I implemented it so far, this is before the password is checked for:

```
export const UseStorage = async (loginInfo) => {
var userLegit = true;
var passLegit = true;

try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/users?user=${loginInfo.username.value}`);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Not a valid username');
    alert("Incorrect username or password. Please try again")
    var userLegit = false;
    console.log(userLegit)
  }
```

The input is being taken in correctly on my form as I am also logging that before the function is ran, but the issue stems once I get into the actual search of the value within the function. Thanks for the help

```
"users": [
{
  "pass": "123",
  "user": "foobar",
  "id": 1
```

Comment: It's likely aa problem with your server. Can you try sharing it?

Comment: @code I added the info of the user I am trying to test. there are more users but this is the format I have for them. Not sure if this is what you meant by me sharing the file

Comment: just a convention use `let` instead of `var`, it is more legit and understandable.

Comment: @KunalTanwar it's not the reason we use let; the benefit is its scoping, which `var` mixes up.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and paste the relevant server code?